# Adding makes no sense

Tags: calculation-puzzle

"Hey! If I were to add 6 to 13 I would get 7!", said Patrick slowly as he blew a stream of suspiciously maroon smoke out through his left nostril while calmly stabbing a funny-looking cigarette into an upturned potty.
"Dude.... That is awesome!" giggled Frank.
Provided that Patrick is not tripping, how does his statement make sense?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Patrick has:

> An extremely alkali solution (something bleach-like) of pH 13
>  If he adds the correct amount of a moderately acidic solution (say, coffee or urine) of pH 6

He'll get:

> A neutral solution of pH 7
>  And Frank saying, "You really do have a plan! Yeah science!"

Comment: This answer should get more upvotes...

Comment: Agreed on ABcDexter, more upvotes!

Answer (score 33):

Okay, well how about

> Base 5031

If we work with this, then

> $6_{5031} + 13_{5031} = 19_{5031} = 5040_{10} = 7!$

Comment: It might be better to show that the entire equation is valid in base 5031, since $(7_{5031})! === (7_{10})!$

Comment: Because they are obviously equivalent (with 7 representable in both bases), I found it unnecessary to explicitly mention.

Answer (score 14):

This is

> base 12 clock arithmetic. If you start with 6 o'clock and add 13 hours you get 7 o'clock.

Comment: As far as i understand this, he is adding 6 to 13 and not 13 to 6... There can't be a 13 as augend in a base12 clock arithmetic

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit of a stretch but it might be that

> they are filling baggies with carefully measured amounts of... oregano.
>  Perhaps because they and many of their friends are chefs.

Patrick is announcing that

> as the thirteenth baggie has only a single ounce of oregano...

If [he] were to add six to thirteen, [he] would get seven

Certainly he is not tripping. His mastery of the subjunctive tense shows that he is of clear mind.

Comment: Who buys their spices in seven-ounce bags?

Comment: yeh.... maybe they are seven-pound bags?? :-)

Comment: In my youth some of my friends were fond of and oregano-like substance that they bought by the ounce in baggies.

Answer (score 8):

Well, they both have the...

> munchies, and they are looking at a take-away menu from their local Chinese.

Patrick noticed that

> No. 6 on the menu is Shrimp, No. 13 on the menu is Fried Rice, and No. 7 is Shrimp Fried Rice. So he's quite right, if you add 6 to 13 you get 7.

Comment: Another example of question being too board?  However, hmm....shrimps.... upvote!

Answer (score -5):

I'm stealing Tom's answer =) :

> it's 13:00 pm, adding 6 hrs will result in 19:00, which is 7 o'clock

Comment: "one should not steal"...that's why another one has to steal his answer too. :p

Comment: @manshu I was editing my answer from "steal" to "borrow" when I see your comment, and now I stopped editing

Comment: look at all these downvotes!  don't be jealous I got the answer =)

Comment: @Alex: No, Tom got the answer.

Comment: @Deusovi  Had Tom read and listened to the comment made on his answer (which incidentally got 5 upvotes) - he would have edited his answer to this one and it would have been accepted...

Comment: there's no such thing as 13:00 pm.  1:00 pm is 1300 hours, but it is considered incorrect to use both 24-hour time and am/pm designations.

Comment: @Vynce .. totally agree in a real world example. However, being in a puzzle SE I would have to totally disagree... :-)

Comment: @Ben I'm not saying the *puzzle* doesn't work. I'm saying the answer's text is wrong.  remove the pm and it's fine (and I did upvote).

Comment: A self-admitted stolen answer should not be the accepted answer, @Ben.

Comment: @Ben Accepting stolen answers, especially ones so arrogantly taken, encourages such behaviour on StackExchange which I think is against the spirit of StackExchange. The comment on Tom's answer reads more like an observation than a correction, so if you truly care to remain within the spirit of SE then I'd recommend commenting on Tom's answer until Tom amends it to your request and then accepting his instead. As it stands, he deserves the upvotes, and Alex deserves the downvotes.

Comment: @Ben heh sorry Ben i think somehow accepting my answer drag you into some arguments.  I was surprise that no one think this question is easy enough that when I said stealing it's merely a joke.  I'm not saying the question is bad, it's just many of the similar questions has been asked

Comment: @Alex yeh... Sorry - I discovered that I can't stand up to social pressure :o). Obvious that you were joking... But things got a little out of hand... Sorry

Comment: @Ben ohh don't take it as a pressure, it's an experience.  Learn from it!  more over, I hope this does not discourage you from posting more puzzles